# How to read Client.postMessage before the page loaded?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a service worker that emits Client.postMessage during fetch when a cached resource has changed. I'm using this to notify the user that they might want to refresh.

My problem is that when the active page resource is changed and the service worker emits that message, the page hasn't loaded yet so no javascript can receive the message.

Is there a better way to handle cases like this rather than using waitUntil to pause a few seconds before emitting the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to write to IndexedDB from the service worker, and then read it when the page loads for the first time, before you establish your `message` listener.

Using the [`ibd-keyval`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb-keyval) library for simplicity's sake, this could look like:

```
// In your service worker:
importScripts('https://unpkg.com/idb-keyval@2.3.0/idb-keyval.js');

async function notifyOfUpdates(urls) {
  const clients = await self.clients.matchAll();
  for (const client of clients) {
    client.postMessage({
      // Structure your message however you'd like:
      type: 'update',
      urls,
    });
  }

  // Read whatever's currently saved in IDB...
  const updatedURLsInIDB = await idb.get('updated-urls') || [];
  // ...append to the end of the list...
  updatedURLsInIDB.push(...urls);
  // ...and write the updated list to IDB.
  await idb.set('updated-urls', updatedURLsInIDB);
}


// In your web page:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/idb-keyval@2.3.0/idb-keyval.js"></script>
<script>
  async listenForUrlUpdates() {
    const updatedURLsInIDB = await idb.get('updated-urls');
    // Do something with updatedURLsInIDB...

    // Clear out the list now that we've read it:
    await idb.delete('updated-urls');

    // Listen for ongoing updates:
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
      if (event.data.type === 'update') {
        const updatedUrls = event.data.urls;
        // Do something with updatedUrls
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```